# Combining mouseEvents on label in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, label, mouseevent

I want to combine MouseEnter with MousePressed on a label.

```
Public Sub populateGrid()
    lblTest.BackColor()
    lblTest.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    gbWorkflow.Controls.Add(lblTest)
    For j As Integer = 1 To 40
        For i As Integer = 1 To 20
            Dim L As New Label
            L.Size = New Size(30, 30)
            L.Text = "L:" + i.ToString + j.ToString
            L.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
            Dim x, y As Integer
            Dim loc As Point = gbWorkflow.Location
            y = loc.Y * (i * 8) '- (gbWorkflow.Height + L.Size.Height) * i
            x = loc.X * (j * 8)

            L.Location = New Point(x, y)

            gbWorkflow.Controls.Add(L)

            AddHandler L.MouseEnter, AddressOf L_Enter
            AddHandler L.MouseLeave, AddressOf L_Leave
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub L_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim TheLabel As Label = CType(sender, Label)
        TheLabel.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub
```

My idea was to create a method that triggers on MouseDown and changes the value of a boolean variable. I would then use that variable as a condition to apply the changes to the labels. However, that doesnt seem to work...

How can I achieve this in the best way? Or, at all?

Pseudo-code:
    When mouse enter label:
        if left mousebutton is pressed then
            do stuff with the label

Edit:
It also has to work when the mousebutton is still pressed and the cursor is dragged over several labels. All the labels that the cursor crosses while the left button is pressed should be changed.

Comment: I did answer before your Edit. Regarding your edit: when you press the button on Label1, a press-button event is associated with this Label1. If you don't release the pressing and move the mouse; the move-mouse event comes into picture (also associated with Label1). If you want to affect other controls with the mouse pressed, you have to rely on drag-drop-type events. Even in this case, you cannot bring new labels into picture before "unpressing the button" (what would "unlock the previous event"). Please, make your ideas clearer and try to not change the question suddenly :)

Comment: I'm really sorry for not being clearer about what I'm trying to acheive! I'm making a grid of labels in a groupbox (gbWorkFlow). The labels in this grid should be markable, and it should be possible to mark them by clicking and dragging. The X-axis of the grid is dates, and the Y-axis is percentages. The user should be able to draw a line across the dates selecting the percentages that apply to each date without having to click on each label individually. the line is not always a straight one, which is the reason I'm trying to make this solution work. Did this clarify my problem?

Comment: From what you say, what you are looking for is: first click in label (as proposed in my original answer... the user does not need to keep the mouse down), move to label2 and a new click (to set a new point) and so on... (this is how drawing tools usually work for that: as many clicks as points to draw lines). I have edited my answer with a new sample code (before reading your explanation): take a look at it and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

The `MouseDown` event delivers what you are after. Sample code:

```
Private Sub L_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
        'Do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Adding the event handler:

```
AddHandler L.MouseDown, AddressOf L_MouseDown
```

--- UPDATE

As said, you cannot accomplish directly what you want but there are many alternative ways to deliver an equivalent performance. For example:

Boolean flag indicating whether one of the target labels has been clicked (`MouseDown`) + `MouseEnter` performing the modifications only if this flag is true. Sample code:

```
Private LWasClicked As Boolean = False


Private Sub L_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And Not LWasClicked) Then
        LWasClicked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub L_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If (LWasClicked) Then
        'Do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

With the code above, you can "activate the editing" by just clicking on any label (or on a specific one); once it is activated, you can just pass the mouse over any label and the actions will be performed. You will also have to set an event to de-activate this behaviour (example: new Click/MouseDown). As you can see, this delivers an equivalent performance to what you want and is compatible with how events work.

CLARIFICATION: I think that this (or any other alternative on these lines) delivers an excellent performance. If still you don't want that and prefer to do everything with the mouse-button pressed, you would have to rely on something different (e.g., position of the mouse on the screen, analysis triggered by other means; or even events from different threads). What is clear is that what you aim cannot be accomplished with one-thread events of different controls (a new event cannot be started before the previous one has ended).

Comment: Sorry, had to edit the question. Your answer works perfectly, but not for multiple labels

Comment: @TM89 I have posted a comment to your EDIT right now. Please, think carefully about what you want exactly (and I will correct my answer accordingly) and bear in mind the minimum conditions: you cannot call a new event before the previous one has ended (in this case, the mouse click has to be released/MouseDown event terminated).